# Problem with circular reference list

Tags: c#, list, circular-reference

I have a small problem and I would like to get your opinion.

I'm dealing with documents than can reference other documents. Starting from any document, I need to get the id of all the documents this document references. The problem is that the circular references are allowed so if A ref B ref C, again C can ref A and I get in the loop.
How can I solve this problem in C#?

An small example:

Let suppose that this is a class that represents a document:

```
public class Document
{
    public Document(int id)
    {
        this.ID = id;
    }

    private int m_ID;

    public int ID
    {
        get { return m_ID; }
        set { m_ID = value; }
    }

    private List<Document> m_Children = new List<Document>();

    public List<Document> Children
    {
        get { return m_Children; }
        set { m_Children = value; }
    }

    private List<Document> m_Parent = new List<Document>();

    public List<Document> Parent
    {
        get { return m_Parent; }
        set { m_Parent = value; }
    }

    public Document AddChild(Document child)
    {
        child.Parent.Add(this);
        this.Children.Add(child);

        return child;
    }

    public Document AddChild(int child)
    {
        Document d = new Document(child);

        return AddChild(d);
    }
}
```

Now let's create a Document class that has some references:

```
public static Document CreateReferences()
{
    Document d = new Document(1);

    Document temp = d.AddChild(2);

    for (int i = 3; i < 6; i++)
    {
        temp = temp.AddChild(i);
    }

    temp.AddChild(d);

    return d;
}
```

Now I need to implement a method in Document class like

```
public List<int> GetReferencedDocuments()
{    }
```

What is the best way to do that? Any specific algorithm can be implemented?

Any suggestion is well accepted!

Thanks

Comment: you want to get all parent references or all references downwards the tree? Btw. (if you're about the parent references) with the circular dependencies: you might just go up the tree and continue up only if the object up isn't already in the list. can't find the problem in this..

Comment: all the references that this document has, including the children references.

Comment: Than as I said you'd have to have to iterate through the references only those-> which has not already been added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any tree-traversal algorithm would be fine.

---

As well as a list of docs you're going to build up, maintain a queue of documents you've yet to check, add the first document to that list.

Then, while the queue isn't empty, get the next doc, if it's not already in your list, then add it, and add all referenced docs to your queue.

---

```
List<Document> FoundDocs = new List<Documents();
Queue<Document> DocsToSearch = new Queue<Document>();

DocsToSearch.Enqueue(StartDoc);

while(DocsToSearch.Count != 0)
{
    Document Doc = DocsToSearch.Dequeue();
    if(!FoundDocs.Contains(Doc))
    {
        FoundDocs.Add(Doc);
        foreach(var ChildDoc in Doc.Children)
        {
            DocsToSearch.Enqueue(ChildDoc);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks! I will now analyse the algorithm. Is there any algorithm that could be faster then this?

Comment: Possible problem: FoundDocs.Contains(Doc) will check for reference equality. If the child doc has been added with the AddChild(int child) method, IDs can be equal without actually referencing the same instance.

Comment: Overriding the default equality comparer of the Document class should do.

Comment: At example by implementing IEquatable<T> interface. I'm I right?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to do a [depth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) or a [breadth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)

Comment: Ok, but a concrete implementation example? I saw that pseudo code, but I was unable to adapt it to C# and concrete problem. Thanks

Comment: @MaiO: You said you were unable to adapt it to C# after 2 minutes of my answer... Don't you think you should give it a try?

Comment: If I was able to implement it, I would not post a question! After a couple of hours thinking about, I decided to post a question.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main approaches to resolving this sort of recursive search on recursive data: marking or recording.

Marking: every time you list a document, flag it as viewed. Do not process flagged documents.

So your GetReferenceDocuments would look a little like this:

> GetReferencedDocuments(startpoint)
>
> if(startpoint.flagged) return null
>
> startpoint.flag
>
> new list result =startpoint
>
> foreach(subdocument in
>
> documents.children)
>
> result.append(getreferenceddocuments(subdocuments))//
>   if not null

Recording: a similar approach, but the flag indicators are replaced by a list of already referenced documents ( a separate list of ids maybe ), and the flag check is a search on this list for this document.

Either way will work, depending on your objects, size and scale. If you cannot change the document objects, you will have to list them. If you have, potentially, 1M documents in your scan, you do not want to list them.

Answer (score 0):

Example implementation:

```
public List<int> GetReferencedDocuments()
{    
    var referencedIds = new List<int>();
    var queue = new Queue<Document>(this);
    while (queue.Count > 0)
    {
         var newDocuments = queue.Dequeue().Children
                                           .Where(d => !referencedIds.Contains(d.ID))
         foreach (Document newDocument in newDocuments) 
         {
             queue.Enqueue(newDocument);
             referencedIds.Add(newDocument.ID);
         }
    }
    return referencedIds;
}
```